# Регулярное выражение для украинского автомобильного номера

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярку для украинского номера. Число должно быть четырехзначным, минимальная цифра 0001, максимальная 9999 Hазрешены 12 букв в латинском алфавите — А, В, С, Е, Н, I, К, М, О, Р, Т, Х.

Например для AA0000AА

Вот что получилось у меня: `/^[АВCEHIKMOPTX]\d{2}(?<!0000)[АВCEHIKMOPTX]{2}$/` (Взял регулярку с российского номера, и поменял ее)

Comment: Нужно больше информации. Какие символы допустимы, какие ограничения на число.

Comment: `/^[АВCEHIKMOPTX]{2}\d{4}[АВCEHIKMOPTX]{2}$/`

Comment: Приведите примеры валидных и невалидных номеров в соответствии с описанием метки [tag:регулярные-выражения]. Из описание никак не следует, что 4 цифры должны быть в середине

Comment: И ваша регулярка не находит же пример `AA0000AА`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем регулярном выражении `А` и `В`в символьных классах кириллические, `&#x0410;` и `&#x0412;` соответственно.

Кроме того, `\d{2}` находит только две цифры, в номере же их четыре.

Используйте

```
^[ABCEHIKMOPTX]{2}\d{4}(?<!0{4})[ABCEHIKMOPTX]{2}$
^[ABCEHIKMOPTX]{2}(?!0{4})\d{4}[ABCEHIKMOPTX]{2}$
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/4OwE80/1/). Схема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[ABCEHIKMOPTX]{2}` - две латниские буквы из заданного набора
- `(?!0{4})` - следующие четыре символа не должны быть `0000`
- `\d{4}` - четыре цифры
- `(?<!0{4})` - предыдущие четыре символа не могут быть `0000`
- `[ABCEHIKMOPTX]{2}` - две латниские буквы из заданного набора
- `$` - конец строки.

Comment: Случайно не вы ставите минусы на мои ответы по регулярным выражениям?